# Why is SetConsoleTitleA not hotpatchable?

Tags: c++, winapi

GetConsoleTitleA is hotpatchable. The first instruction is `mov edi, edi` and the function itself it preceded by 5 `nop`s. However SetConsoleTitleA starts with  `push 0C`.

Why is it so?

OS: Windows 7 x86-64.

Comment: Are asking why it starts with `push 0C`, or why `push 0C` is not hot-patchable?

Comment: @sashoalm, both. Microsoft's own documentation tells me that all their images are hotpatchable and the execution of each function starts with mov edi, edi. So why are some functions not like that?

Comment: Where can I find such a documentation???

Answer (score 1):

> [[...] the compiler ensures that **first instruction of each function is at least two bytes, which is required for hot patching**.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173507.aspx)

`push 0Ch` is a two-byte instruction, hence the hotpatchability and the answer to the title question.

```
74E567D3 90                   nop  
74E567D4 90                   nop  
74E567D5 90                   nop  
74E567D6 90                   nop  
74E567D7 90                   nop  
_SetConsoleTitleA@4:
74E567D8 6A 0C                push        0Ch  
74E567DA 68 30 68 E5 74       push        74E56830h  
74E567DF E8 DC AD F5 FF       call        __SEH_prolog4 (74DB15C0h)
```